# Formatting the whole number not just decimal figures in android/java

Tags: java, android, number-formatting

If i had a number like 58998741.348912.

I want to change it something like #####.#### (58900.3490). I need to format both before and after decimal.

my array

```
public double[] usgArray = {1, 4, 8, 16, 128, 256, 768, 0.00378541, 3.78541, 3785.41, 0.832674, 3.3307, 6.66139, 133.228, 213.165, 639.494, 0.133681, 231};
public double[] someArray = {...........}
..... 
.........
for(int i=0;i<= (usgArray.length)-1;i++){
        String.format("%.6f",usgArray[i]);
        String.format("%.6f",someArray[i]);
        ........
        .............
}
Log.d("this is my array", "arr: " + Arrays.toString(usgArray));
```

My log result :

```
this is my array: arr: [1.0, 4.0, 8.0, 16.0, 128.0, 256.0, 768.0, 0.00378541, 3.78541, 3785.41, 0.832674, 3.3307, 6.66139, 133.228, 213.165, 639.494, 0.133681, 231.0]
```

nothing really changed..

I also tried Decimal Format, did not work wither,

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.####");
df.format(some double value);
```

Comment: What is you expected result exactly?

Comment: something like #####.####
5 digits before decimal and 4 digits after decimal

Comment: `If i had a number like 58998741.348912.I want to change it something like #####.#### (58900.3490)` So, you want a **false** result. Because the decimal part is absolutely out of place, once you round up the integer part. Also note that you divided the integer part by 1000 (How does **58,998,741**, which is about 59 **MILLIONS** become **58,900**, which is about 59 **THOUSANDS**?)... Therefore, you want a **false** result.

Comment: This is quite a silly question. But you can do what you're up to, by converting the number to string, splitting it by '.', converting both parts into `double` and rounding them in some way, then concatenating them back

Answer (score 0):

`String.format("%.6f",usgArray[i]);` **not** changes `usgArray[i]` but returns a string, so you have to rewrite this row in the next way:

`usgArray[i] = Double.parse(String.format("%.6f", usgArray[i]));`

but easier way is to use:

`usgArray[i] = (double) Math.round(usgArray[i] * 1000000d) / 1000000d;`

this is for 6 digits precision. The number of zeros indicate the number of decimals.

**update**

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(String.format("%f", format(58998741.348912, 5, 4)));
     }

     public static double format(double number, int beforeDot, int afterDot) {
         String[] parts = String.format("%f", number).split("\\.");
         if (parts.length < 2) {
             return number;
         }
         return Double.parseDouble(cutNumber(parts[0], beforeDot) + "." + cutNumber(parts[1], afterDot));
     }

     public static String cutNumber(String number, int signs) {
         return number.length() < signs ? number + getZeros(signs - number.length()) : number.substring(0, signs);
     }

     public static String getZeros(int count) {
         String zeros = "";
         for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
             zeros+="0";
         }
         return zeros;
     }
}
```

Comment: ya, working fine for decimals, i also need to format the numbers before decimals too.
Is there any solution for it ?

Comment: yep, everything is possible, but could you give an example of such formatting? what do you expect?

Comment: The first two lines of the question : 
If i had a number like 58998741.348912.

I want to change it something like #####.#### (58900.3490).

Comment: please see update answer. play with this code, this is quite close to your requirements. you can pass any positive number as `beforeDot` and `afterDot` args

Comment: @Mann did my example help you?